# Ember.Application.create vs Ember.Application.extend

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I noticed that in the `app.js` file produced by Ember CLI (v0.1.12), they're using:

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({...})
```

but in the [introduction guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/application/), they're using:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({...});
```

Is there any difference in outcome between these two (create vs. extend) ways of creating an Ember application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the Ember documentation [`extend` *Creates a new subclass,*](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_extend) while 
[`create` *Creates an instance of a class*](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_create).

The main difference is that by using `extend`

> you can override methods but still access the implementation of your
>   parent class by calling the special _super() method

but `create` does not afford that ability.

The linked docs have good code examples specifically with regards to your question.

See

> The create() on line #17 creates an instance of the App.Soldier class.
>   The extend() on line #8 creates a subclass of App.Person. Any instance
>   of the App.Person class will not have the march() method.

and the code proceding that quote.